# Math.min.apply returns 0 for null

Tags: javascript

I would like to get minimum value from an array. If the data contains `null` value, `Math.min.apply` returns `0` for `null` value. Please see [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jeryslo/7DCXw/). How can I get true minimum value even if null value exists in array?

Code (same as in JSFiddle example):

```
var arrayObject= [ {"x": 1, "y": 5}, {"x": 2, "y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 9}, {"x": 4, "y": null}, {"x": 5, "y": 12} ];

var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arrayObject.map(function(o){return o.y;}));
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, arrayObject.map(function(o){return o.y;}));

$("#max").text(max);
$("#min").text(min);
```

Comment: There is no JSON in your example... fixed.

Comment: The `Math.min` function performs (the internal function) `ToNumber()` on each array element, which in turn coerces the values to *Number*. Coercion sucks, we knew that. `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas simply leaving the property out would make it `undefined`, which in turn turns to `NaN` which is easily filtered out with  `.filter(isFinite)`

Comment: @Esailija Yes, that would be a great solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, the numerical value for `null` is `0`. If you don't want `null` values to be be considered, you have to filter them out:

```
var values = arrayObject.map(function(o){
    return o.y;
}).filter(function(val) {
    return val !== null
});
```

**Reference**: [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Or map `null` to `Infinity`. Would save some bytes and additional `n` function calls.

Comment: @Prinzhorn: Yeah, that would work too... just that you have to map them again for `max` to `-Infinity`. Depends on what you are going to do with the data.

Comment: Is this right? I am still getting 0, look here at forked version:http://jsfiddle.net/jeryslo/nfSUm/

Comment: @Jernej: You only used the filtered values for `max`, not for `min`.

Answer (score 8):

Alternative to Felix's solution: treat `null` as `+` or `-` infinity for min and max calls, respectively.

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arrayObject.map(function(o) {
    return o.y == null ? -Infinity : o.y;
}));
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, arrayObject.map(function(o) {
    return o.y == null ? Infinity : o.y;
}));
```

Comment: Vow. I've never seen infinity been put to use. I'd upvote this twice if I could. :)

Comment: Is there a reason to use the constant on `Number`, wouldn't the literal `Infinity` (and `-Infinity`) be easier?

Answer (score 4):

I think instead of mapping properties, filtering out `null` values, and applying `Math.min/max` (as suggested by the other answers) the [`reduce` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will save you some time and code, by directly applying the logic:

```
var arrayObject= [ {"x": 1, "y": 5}, {"x": 2, "y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 9}, {"x": 4, "y": null}, {"x": 5, "y": 12} ];
var min = var arrayObject.reduce(function(m, o) {
    return (o.y != null && o.y < m) ? o.y : m;
}, Infinity);
var max = var arrayObject.reduce(function(m, o) {
    return (o.y != null && o.y > m) ? o.y : m;
}, -Infinity);
```

Comment: Interesting solution. What is the performance gain in terms of O notation?

Comment: `O(n)` not unlike any other solution.

Comment: Landau notation? None. But you save some function calls and some memory by not creating the intermediate arrays

Answer (score 1):

These are what I've been using in 2020. Slightly shorter code.

```js
const min = (values) => values.reduce((m, v) => (v != null && v < m ? v : m), Infinity);
const max = (values) => values.reduce((m, v) => (v != null && v > m ? v : m), -Infinity);

const arrayObject = [
  { x: 1, y: 5 },
  { x: 2, y: 2 },
  { x: 3, y: 9 },
  { x: 4, y: undefined },
  { x: 5, y: 12 },
];
const yValues = arrayObject.map((item) => item.y)

console.log(yValues)
console.log('min', min(yValues))
console.log('max', max(yValues))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var validArray = $.grep( arrayObject, function(item, _){
                    return item.y != null;
               });
//That gives a new array without null values for "y"
```

Now do..

```
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, validArray.map(function(o){return o.y;}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash:

```js
_.min([5, null]) = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This one seems the cleanest and worked best for me:

```
const applicableValues = originalData.filter(o => Number.isInteger(o[propertyName])); // or o[propertyName]!== null

const minValue = Math.min(...applicableValues.map(o => o[propertyName]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.min(...[...arrayObject.filter(n => n["y"] != null)].map(a=>a["y"]))
```

pull out the null values, then create array of the y values, then grab the minimum from that array

Answer (score -1):

have you tried the conditional (ternary) operator in the min function

(**if Value is Null**  ? "a large value so that does not fall min criteria " : "original value")

Hope this helps!